Gosperable formulas
Below we give examples of Gosperable formulas
\begin{align}
& (1) \quad \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac12)_n^6}{(1)_n^6} \, \frac{1-12n^2+48n^4}{(1-2n)^3} = \frac{8}{\pi^3}, \\
& (2) \quad \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac12)_n^8}{(1)_n^8} \, \frac{1-16n^2+96n^4-256n^6}{(1-2n)^4} = \frac{16}{\pi^4}, \\
& (3) \quad \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac12)_n^{10}}{(1)_n^{10}} \frac{1-20n^2+160n^4-640n^6+1280n^8}{(1-2n)^5} = \frac{32}{\pi^5}, \\
& (4) \quad \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac12)_n^4}{(1)_n^4} \frac{8n^2+8n+1}{(n+1)^2} = \frac{16}{\pi^2}, \\
& (5) \quad \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac12)_n^6}{(1)_n^6} \frac{(12n^2+10n+1)(12n^2+18n+7)}{(n+1)^4} = \frac{256}{\pi^3}. 
\end{align}
We can prove this kind of formulas automatically using Gosper's algorithm. For example, we see that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{m} \frac{(\frac12)_n^6}{(1)_n^6} \frac{(12n^2+10n+1)(12n^2+18n+7)}{(n+1)^4} = A(m),
$$
where
$$
A(m)=\frac{(\frac12)_n^6}{(1)_n^6} \frac{(2m+1)^6(4m+7)}{(m+1)^4}.
$$
For checking it, observe that
$$
A(m)-A(m-1) = \frac{(\frac12)_m^6}{(1)_m^6} \frac{(12m^2+10m+1)(12m^2+18m+7)}{(m+1)^4}.
$$
Hence the sum of the infinite series is equal to the limit of $A(m)$ that we find easily using Stirling's formula.
Questions:
1-) We ask for other examples of Gospereable formulas not very similar to the given above.
2-) Are all hypergeometric series with $z=1$ and a known sum Gospereable?
3-) Is it possible for some of the examples to introduce a free parameter $k$ such that they turn WZ (Wilf-Zeilberger) provable? The advantage of it will be that the generalization may allow improving the rate of convergence by using WZ-transformations, for example $k\to k+n$.
An example of question 3-) for formula (4) is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac12\right)_n^3 \left(1+\frac{k}{2}\right)_n \left(\frac12+\frac{k}{2} \right)_n}{(1)_n^3(1+k)_n^2} \frac{\left(\frac12\right)_k^2}{(1)_k^2} \, \frac{4k(8n^2+6kn+2n+k)}{2n+k} = \frac{16}{\pi^2}
$$
Observe that the case $k=1$ is exactly the formula (4). Then, due to the free parameter $k$ we can accelerate it by means of transformations of the form $F(n,k) \to F(i \, n, k \pm j \, n)$, where $i,j \in \{1,2,...\}$ (arXiv:1003.1915).

for "Gosper with free paramaters", see https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/download/v11i1r53/pdf

Is the meaning of "Gosperable" "able to be proved by Gosper's algorithm"?

@LSpice Yes, with the term Gosperable I mean exactly that

This is found using PSLQ. I guess it is "Gosperable" $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{64}\right)^n\cdot\frac{(1)_n^7}{(\frac{1}{2})_n^7}\cdot\frac{21n^3 + 41n^2 + 27n + 6}{(2n+1)^7}=\frac{\pi^4}{16}$$

@JorgeZuniga For a series to be  Gosperable we need to obtain the partial sum, and being able to get the limit of it. This is not the case of the series you show. Note: Maple finds directly the partial sum in case it exists.

@Jesus_Guillera, thanks doctor. I see. A PSLQ search with z=1 for similar hypergeometric estructures as those examples, using smart ansatz’s for denominators could give gosperable expresions if their partial sums can be evaluated in closed form.
